# Python - Unnest List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Is there a neater more pythonic way to unnest this list of dictionaries?

**Example:**

```
features = [{'annual_sales_revenue': {'definition': 'yearly revenue generated'}}, {'dnb_annual_employees': {'definition': 'number of employees'}}, {'global_industry_hospitality': {'definition': 'in hospitality industry'}}, {'itbuyindex': {'definition': "company's capacity to invest in technology"}}, {'test': {'definition': 'test'}}]
```

**My Solution:**

```
{list(f.keys())[0]:f[list(f.keys())[0]]['definition'] for f in features}
```

**Desired Result:**

```
{'annual_sales_revenue': 'yearly revenue generated', 'dnb_annual_employees': 'number of employees', 'global_industry_hospitality': 'in hospitality industry', 'itbuyindex': "company's capacity to invest in technology", 'test': 'test'}
```

Comment: No - that's a nested dict of dicts. So the solutions don't solve my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a double for-loop with a dictionary comprehension:

```
features = [{'annual_sales_revenue': {'definition': 'yearly revenue generated'}}, {'dnb_annual_employees': {'definition': 'number of employees'}}, {'global_industry_hospitality': {'definition': 'in hospitality industry'}}, {'itbuyindex': {'definition': "company's capacity to invest in technology"}}, {'test': {'definition': 'test'}}]
result = {a:b['definition'] for i in features for a, b in i.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'annual_sales_revenue': 'yearly revenue generated', 'dnb_annual_employees': 'number of employees', 'global_industry_hospitality': 'in hospitality industry', 'itbuyindex': "company's capacity to invest in technology", 'test': 'test'}
```

Comment: That looks much neater! Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

```py
{key: d[key]['definition'] for d in features for key in d}
```

I slightly prefer this, feel its a bit cleaner